# Set a variable to what json_encode() outputs in PHP

Tags: php, json

json_encode() returns a string...

So shouldn't the following code work?

```
class TestClass {
    private $test = json_encode("test");
}
```

PHP outputs

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/testuser/public_html/test.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not assign expression or any variable while declaring class property. The literal constants such as `__FILE__` are allowed here.

they have to be a literal value, such as a string, or a constant.

There all work.

```
private $test= 98;
private $test= "test value";
private $test= CONSTANT;
private $test= __FILE__;
```

But these will not

```
private $test= 98*2;
private $test= "test value"."some other value";
```

You can use constructor

```
 function __construct() {
        $this->test = json_encode("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you cannot assign an instance variable to the result of a function in the declaration. You should assign it in the constructor. Eg.

```
class TestClass {
    private $test;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->test = json_encode("test");
    }
}
```